# Is it correct to call an error created with Swift's keyword "throw" an "exception"?

Tags: swift, error-handling

Error handling using the keywords `throw`, `throws`, `do`, `try`, and `catch` was introduced in version 2 of Swift. In [the relevant chapter of the official Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) the word *exception* is not used, but it is stated:

> Error handling in Swift resembles exception handling in other
>   languages, with the use of the try, catch and throw keywords. Unlike
>   exception handling in many languages—including Objective-C—error
>   handling in Swift does not involve unwinding the call stack, a process
>   that can be computationally expensive.

So just because the call stack is missing it cannot be called an exception? (Is there a scientific definition for the features an error handling mechanism has to provide to be called as *exception*?)

Comment: Question is opinion based. And swift developer can call it `error handling` instead of `exception handling` for same reason they call `protocol` what in other languages is called `interface`. Just because they can and they want it to be named like that.

Comment: My question is about the strict meaning of the term `exception` in the programming language Swift. I agree with Benjamin Lowry statement that most Swift programmers will accept the term `exception` in an informal way. I think calling a `protocol an *interface* in Swift is wrong in the strict sense.

Comment: Is there strict meaning? And exactly what in `Swift` is called `protocol` in languages like `Java`, `C#`, `C++` and some others is called `interface`. So why is it *wrong in the strict sense*?

Comment: Apple as creator of the language `Swift` chose to call it `protocol` instead of `interface`, so in the (very) strict sense it is incorrect to call `protocols` in Swift `interfaces`. Would a strict university professor accept the term `interface` in a exam paper about the Swift programming language?

Comment: Apple as creator of the language `Swift` chose to call it `Error handling` instead of `Exception handling`. Would a strict university professor accept the term `exception handling` in a exam paper about the Swift programming language? *See, same explanation, as i said in original comment*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that why it is called error handling has nothing to do with the call stack. This is corroborated by the fact that based on the definitions of both words, the call stack is irrelevant. I believe that the purpose of the quote that you have included in your question is merely to provide a distinction between error-handling in Swift and exception-handling in other languages, disregarding the differences in names.

To identify the distinction in terms of non-swift languages, a common description is that it is an error not to handle an exception. Thus an error and an exception are two unique entities.

Now in Swift, it seems that they have tried to completely get rid of the word "exception" in favor of just using the term error. Thus an error can be dealt with, and if not, the program crashes. This is likely because it is not as important what the actual crash is called, and what is more important is what caused it, in this case an "error".

In terms of usage in the iOS world, I have little experience in this, but I would assume that even though to call it "exception handling" is not technically correct, most Swift programmers would know what you are talking about and probably not correct you (or even think to correct you).

Overall, I think it is mostly a matter of semantics, and not what constitutes an "error" and what constitutes an "exception".

**Edit**

I should clarify that I mean that the difference between errors and exceptions *within iOS/Swift* is not just semantics. Exceptions are what are thrown when illegal things happen, and errors can be created to allow you to prevent these messages from being shown/your program crashing. In this respect they are completely different things.

My point is that among different coding languages the term "error" (in Swift) and "exception" (in Java for example) are basically the same, just with different names.

For example, I could try and deal with an error named "ArrayError" (stupid name I know, it's just for an example) where as in Java I could be trying to catch IndexOutOfBoundsException. Both of these objects are both thrown and caught, and thus I am drawing a comparison between the two highlighting the differences in naming conventions in Swift vs other languages.

But no, errors and exceptions are not technically the same thing, even in Swift.

Comment: Coming from `Java`, I always thought that exceptions are a special kind of error handling which has the advantage that you do not have to deal with return codes. If you have to invoke several functions/methods in a sequence, without exceptions in this sense you need need nested `if`-statements to decide after each invocation if you can invoke the next method. These nested `if`-statements for error handling are also known as *Pyramid of Doom*. Exceptions in this sense help to separate the business logic from the error handling.